# How do i make a rounded input text field with the ability to change stroke color and stroke width in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

[image]

Im trying to create this in kivy. Its not coming out as planned.

Here is the code i have so far:

```
               MDTextFieldRound:
                    id: category_search
                    icon_right: 'magnify'
                    icon_right_color: 1,1,1,1
                    size_hint_x: .9
                    hint_text: 'search category'
                    helper_text: "This will disappear when you click off"
                    helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': 1}
                    max_text_length: 20
                    color_mode: 'accent'
                    normal_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    line_color_focus: 1, 1, 1, 1
                    line_color_normal: 1, 1, 1, 1
                    color_active: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    helper_text: 'search members in specific category'

                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
                    canvas.after:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
                        Ellipse:
                            angle_start:180
                            angle_end:360
                            pos:(self.pos[0] - self.size[1]/2.0, self.pos[1])
                            size: (self.size[1], self.size[1])
                        Ellipse:
                            angle_start:360
                            angle_end:540
                            pos: (self.size[0] + self.pos[0] - self.size[1]/2.0, self.pos[1])
                            size: (self.size[1], self.size[1])
                        Color:
                            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
                        Line:
                            points: self.pos[0] , self.pos[1], self.pos[0] + self.size[0], self.pos[1]
                        Line:
                            points: self.pos[0], self.pos[1] + self.size[1], self.pos[0] + self.size[0], self.pos[1] + self.size[1]
                        Line:
                            ellipse: self.pos[0] - self.size[1]/2.0, self.pos[1], self.size[1], self.size[1], 180, 360
                        Line:
                            ellipse: self.size[0] + self.pos[0] - self.size[1]/2.0, self.pos[1], self.size[1], self.size[1], 360, 540
```

I get this result when trying this:

[image]

Disregard the red border, thats just the background on which it sits.

How do i get a clean rounded border like the first image thats about 2px wide and where the magnify icon stays the same color white wether im clicked in typing inside it or not?

Comment: Try changing the second `'Color` (after the two `Ellipse` instructions) to `rgba: 1,1,1,1`.

Comment: that seemed to work....somewhat.  the entire field doesn't turn faint, nor jet black when clicked inside of it. The two black endcaps still persist....not really what i want. Also, the stroke  is very thin. How do i thicken the stroke line?

Comment: In addition to the `points` attribute, the `Line` also has a `width` that defaults to `1.0`. You can set it to anything you want.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.html#kivy.graphics.Line).